# Uncaught TypeError: list.forEach is not a function get

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setAllLoading(true);
    setSelected(initalValues);
    GetApiHandler({
      url:
        "/Taxes/GetTaxByGst/" + gstPercent + "/" + authStore.userDetails.branch,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        let tempValues = initalValues;

        for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
          const element = res[index];
          // accountHeadNameList.findIndex(c=>c==)

          accountHeadNameList.forEach((name) => {
            if (element.flag === valuesFlags[name].flag) {
              let objectData = { id: element.ledgerId, name: element.name };
              tempValues[name] = objectData;
            }
          });
        }
        setSelected(tempValues);
        setAllLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setAllLoading(false);
      });

    //   refGST.current = gstPercent;
  }, [gstPercent, authStore.userDetails.branch]);
```

in the above code m getting memory leak I used to do like

```
     setSelected((v) => {
            return { ...v, [name]: objectData };
          });
```

set the values inside the if statement and set for each object this works fine
but since am setting each time it takes time to set
but if I do it by putting in temporary object than it loads faster but when go to refresh get the error

Any solution or should I just stick to the slow loading
cuz the slow loading is not that slow few or 1 second something

Comment: Can you check where do you have `accountHeadNameList` delared/defined? and if it is defined as array or it is defined as null? Here is your `accountHeadNameList` variable is defined as anything other than an array then it throws this error.

Comment: i am getting array from out side the main component where intial values are declare as 
  const accountHeadNameList = Object.keys(valuesFlags);
and valuesflag contains object like const valuesflag = {name1:{},name2:{},name3:{}} @MehulThakkar